# How to set default language in GeoNetwork 3.0?

Tags: geonetwork, internationalization

I have GeoNetwork 3.0.4 running and every time I go to the address, it redirects me to the Portuguese version

```
geonetwork/srv/por/catalog.search#/home
```

I'd like for all users to load only the site in the English language

```
geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/home
```

Where are those settings controlled? I tried changing the settings in config.xml but that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

GeoNetwork automatically detects the default language from the browser and redirects to that language. You will have to override that to avoid this redirection.

Check the Spring MVC configuration here: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/5f886f80c76b2c88c1f4c13a07aa1f017cdcdb0c/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml#L24

Comment: sorry for digging this out but I might be missing a crucial point here: My spring-servlet.xml says exactly that:
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="eng" />
But the browser always changes back to German. How can I make it permanently taking english.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at CatController.js and the Spring  MVC but couldnt do much.

I managed to set everything in english (one language only) by manipulating the HTTP headers passed from Nginx to geonetwork

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939171/mapping-accept-language-header-to-domain-with-nginx-and-django

```py
 location /geonetwork {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language 'en-US';
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```